# I have problem with sorting my array and I don`t know why

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, sorting, vuejs2

my code have problem and I don`t know why   it`s not working and always give difrent erros
I tried anyway
the error:
'arraysorted' is not defined  no-undef

```
 <div>
   {{ arraysorted }}
 </div>
</template>

<script>
const Array = [];
export default {
 data: () => ({
   Array: [1, 24, 23, 56, 76, 5, 468, 97, 65, 90, 23, 53, 23],
   arraysorted: [],
 }),
 mounted: {
   ArraySort() {
     return arraysorted = Array.sort(function (a, b) {
       return b - a;
     });
   },
 },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Don't call your array `Array`, it's very confusing. You may call it `array` but not `Array` because that is the class of all arrays, and you will be shadowing other functions like `Array.from`. Also, you sort an empty array... It seems you have not yet understood scope and object properties, that would be topics to read up on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use computed property:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data: () => ({
    myArray: [1, 24, 23, 56, 76, 5, 468, 97, 65, 90, 23, 53, 23],
  }),
  computed: {
    arraysorted() {
      const arrSorted = [...this.myArray]
      return arrSorted.sort((a, b) => b - a)
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  {{ arraysorted }}
  {{myArray}}
</div>
```

Comment: That is a confusing computed property given that it also changes the "uncomputed" one as a side effect.

Answer (score 0):

`mounted()` life cycle hook invoked once component mounted. Hence, Instead of writing a method in mounted, You can directly do the sorting and assign the results into `arraysorted` variable.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    Array: [1, 24, 23, 56, 76, 5, 468, 97, 65, 90, 23, 53, 23],
    arraysorted: []
  },
  mounted() {
    this.arraysorted = this.Array.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <pre>{{ arraysorted }}</pre>
</div>
```